# A problem with a .htaccess file and URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my main site in /2011/ folder (so, not in the root)

Screenshot: http://www.ivanhalen.com/htaccess/tree.png

Below is my .htaccess files, and mod_rewrite on Apache server is on

htaccess: http://www.ivanhalen.com/htaccess/htaccess.txt

All is working very nice, but I have a big problem with "extra/" part of the .htaccess file.

I double checked folders and files, but when I try to go to http://www.myserver.com/2011/extra/presentazione/ I am redirected to the 404 error page, and the same if I go to http://www.myserver.com/2011/extra/contatti/

But I'm sure the files are there, infact I can access them respectively on http://www.myserver.com/2011/extra/presentazione.php?iModule=4 and http://www.myserver.com/2011/extra/contatti.php?iModule=4

More, no problem on "/world" section, that follows almost the same rules. And even more, the problem occurs only on a Linux server, not on my local Windows server (Apache powered)

So, what's wrong? Can you help me, please?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Have you checked all the line-end characters on the Linux version? Whenever I have problems with mod_rewrite, it's nearly always the line-endings :/

Comment: @derobert: I'm trying to enable logging, but apache keeps saying "RewriteLog not allowed here" (I'm putting that directive in the .htaccess file)
@Kalessin: line-end charachters? Uhm... sorry, I'm new to Linux environment, what should I check?

Comment: @Ivan: You need to put your RewriteLog in your VirtualHost section in your Apache config (or in the main server config). That's what  "Context: server config, virtual" host means in that documentation. Unfortunately, it can not go in an .htaccess file.

Comment: @derobert: ok, thanks :-) got it, I have the rewrite.log but... It's fine in my local environment, so I should enable the error log on the real server... but it's a shared one, so I don't know what to do...
Can the local log help you?

Comment: @Ivan: A shared server should have a vhost config for you. Hopefully you can add it there (or maybe in the control panel for the server, depends hosting company). I doubt the local one will be of much use since it works, except that by comparing the local and server one, you should be able to spot the difference easily.

Comment: @Ivan: Under Windows, line-endings are signified by two invisible characters, the carriage return (CR) and the line feed (LF). Under Linux, line endings are signified by LF only. If you can edit the .htaccess file using a web-based editor on your shared server for example, this should save the file with the correct line endings for the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I asked the provider staff, and they solved the problem adding the line:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Quite obscure to me, but it works...
Thanks to all!